# Add Two Numbers Algo Understanding

Tags: javascript

I was doing following leetcode question:

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative
>   integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their
>   nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a
>   linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except
>   the number 0 itself.

For which I stumbled upon following algo

```
function ListNode(val) {
      this.val = val;
      this.next = null;
 }

 //This functiomn is called
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {    
    let remainder = 0
    let l3 = {}
    let head = l3
    while (l1 || l2 || remainder) {
        let sum = remainder
        function sumList (linkedList) {
            if (linkedList) {
                sum += linkedList.val
                return linkedList.next
            }
            return null
        }
        l1 = sumList(l1)
        l2 = sumList(l2)
        if (sum>9) {
            remainder = 1
            sum -= 10
        } else {
            remainder = 0
        }

        head.next = new ListNode(sum)
        head = head.next
    }
    return l3.next
};
```

Here, I am unable to comprehend the point of l3? If i remove it the algo fails?

Question Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

Comment: `l3` maintains the original value of `head`; note that `head` changes in the course of the loop.

Comment: @Pointy Still unable to comprehend  your comment. Can you please explain it in more details? as in answer?

Comment: What is a *linked list*? Never heard or read that term.

Comment: @connexo https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/linked-list/

Comment: So in Javascript, that would be a `Map`?

Comment: @connexo Yeah or an object like this const `someObj = { val: 5, next: { val:6: next:null}}` Where `val` contains current value and `next` holds value to next node

Comment: @connexo it's one of the fundamental data structures in Computing Science.

Comment: Look at the code!  The variable `head` changes, but `l3` does not. It maintains the reference to the *head8 of the newly-built result list. Without that, you'd have nothing to return.

Comment: Was my answer satisfactory? If so, please mark one with an accepted checkmark and upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

l3 is there to keep a record of all the values that have been changed for head. If I say that:

```
var a = {};
var b = a;
```

Then b is not its own object. It's a pointer to the same exact object as a, so if you change a value in b, a updates to reflect that change as well.

That is still the case when you dive deeper into nested objects. If I say that:

```
var c = {value: 1, next:{innerValue: 1}};
var d = c;
d.value = 2;
```

Then c updates to reflect the new value as well, as I've already explained. But the interesting part is that if I then go on to assign d to the nested object and edit the nested object, like so:

```
d = d.next;
d.innerValue = 2;
```

That still updates c! So c is keeping a record of all of these updates, while d is free to dive deeper into its nested objects. After running this code, c and d will look like this:

```
console.log(c);//{value: 2, next:{innerValue: 2}}
console.log(d);//{innerValue: 2}
```

This is what l3 does. l3 is to head as c is to d, so when the algorithm says:

```
head.next = new ListNode(sum)
head = head.next
```

...you don't have to worry about losing your history because l3 is keeping a record of everything.